# How to insert / extract a pdf into / from mysql blob using Workbench and Access

Tags: mysql, pdf, encryption, ms-access-2010

Shortening my question.   I have a MySQL v5.5 database with a medium BLOB which contains encrypted PDF images.

My FE is Access 2010 with a link to the documents table in MySQL.

**I am trying to find a way display the image from VBA code in Access.**

Table: documents
Columns:

```
idnum mediumint(7) UN AI PK 
filename varchar(16) 
pdf mediumblob 
udate timestamp
```

I have been doing research and have not found a good solution yet.
I am able to run  MySQL Stored Procedures to Insert encrypted and DumpFile decrypted files into / out of the BLOB from within Access.

Any guidance or samples would be very helpful.

Comment: How about 1 very focused problem that a human could decipher and solve?

Comment: Very good point Drew!  I did change the question to just asking about displaying a MySQL BLOB using Access VBA code.

Comment: There's plenty of examples on Microsoft's site - a simple google seacrh comes up with "How to read and write blobs"